# lxml.etree, element.text doesn't return the entire text from an element

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree, xml.etree

I scrapped some html via xpath, that I then converted into an etree.  Something similar to this:

```
<td> text1 <a> link </a> text2 </td>
```

but when I call element.text, I only get text1 (It must be there, when I check my query in FireBug, the text of the  elements is highlighted, both the text before and after the embedded anchor elements...

Comment: This is one way to do it (code snippet from my little python scrape processor).  Wonder if this is a lxml bug?

Comment: Here's the code snippet:

Comment: if element.tag == "td":
    children = element.getchildren()
    if len(children) > 0:
     topic = (element.text + children[0].tail)
    else:
     topic = element.text
    print("\tTopic:\t\t%s" % topic)

Answer (score 18):

Use `element.xpath("string()")` or `lxml.etree.tostring(element, method="text")` - see [the documentation](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-contain-text).

Comment: toString(element, method="text") almost works, but it also returns the text of the embedded anchor element, which I don't want.

Comment: element.text + child.tail works, but I wish element.text worked the way I want it to :)

Comment: element.xpath("string()") returns same result as *.tostring().  I tried xpath("text()") which doesn't return the text of the anchor element, but it returns a list of 2 strings.  Thanks for pointing out some stuff though.

Answer (score 10):

As a public service to people out there who may be as lazy as I am.  Here's some code from above that you can run.

```
from lxml import etree

def get_text1(node):
    result = node.text or ""
    for child in node:
        if child.tail is not None:
            result += child.tail
    return result

def get_text2(node):
    return ((node.text or '') +
            ''.join(map(get_text2, node)) +
            (node.tail or ''))

def get_text3(node):
    return (node.text or "") + "".join(
        [etree.tostring(child) for child in node.iterchildren()])


root = etree.fromstring(u"<td> text1 <a> link </a> text2 </td>")

print root.xpath("text()")
print get_text1(root)
print get_text2(root)
print root.xpath("string()")
print etree.tostring(root, method = "text")
print etree.tostring(root, method = "xml")
print get_text3(root)
```

Output is:

```
snowy:rpg$ python test.py 
[' text1 ', ' text2 ']
 text1  text2 
 text1  link  text2 
 text1  link  text2 
 text1  link  text2 
<td> text1 <a> link </a> text2 </td>
 text1 <a> link </a> text2
```

Answer (score 7):

looks like an lxml bug to me, but according to design if you read the documentation. I've solved it like this:

```
def node_text(node):
    if node.text:
        result = node.text
    else:
        result = ''
    for child in node:
        if child.tail is not None:
            result += child.tail
    return result
```

Comment: It's not a bug, actually it's the feature that allows you to interpose text among subelements when building an XML element: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38520331/694360

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I guess that is useful, but imho it would be a lot clearer if `.text` would just return the full text and some other suitably named property would contain only the part up to the first subelement. How about `node.head`. This also gives a clue that what you'll want next is `child.tail` without having to stackoverflow first.

Answer (score 7):

Another thing that seems to be working well to get the text out of an element is `"".join(element.itertext())`

Answer (score 3):

```
<td> text1 <a> link </a> text2 </td>
```

Here's how it is (ignoring whitespace):

```
td.text == 'text1'
a.text == 'link'
a.tail == 'text2'
```

If you don't want a text that is inside child elements then you could collect only their tails:

```
text = td.text + ''.join([el.tail for el in td])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_text_recursive(node):
    return (node.text or '') + ''.join(map(get_text_recursive, node)) + (node.tail or '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `element` is equal to `<td>`. You can do the following.

```
element.xpath('.//text()')
```

It will give you a list of all text elements from `self` (the meaning of the dot). `//` means that it will take all elements and finally `text()` is the function to extract text.

Answer (score 0):

```
element.xpath('normalize-space()') also works.
```

Comment: Only pasting code is not enough. You should also explain why it works :)