# Speedier/less resource-demolishing way to strip html from large files than BeautifulSoup? Or, a better way to use BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, parsing, performance, beautifulsoup

Currently I am having trouble typing this because, according to `top`, my processor is at 100% and my memory is at 85.7%, all being taken up by python.

Why? Because I had it go through a 250-meg file to remove markup. 250 megs, that's it! I've been manipulating these files in python with so many other modules and things; BeautifulSoup is the first code to give me any problems with something so small. How are nearly 4 gigs of RAM used to manipulate 250megs of html?

The one-liner that I found (on stackoverflow) and have been using was this:

```
''.join(BeautifulSoup(corpus).findAll(text=True))
```

Additionally, this seems to remove everything BUT markup, which is sort of the opposite of what I want to do. I'm sure that BeautifulSoup can do that, too, but the speed issue remains.

Is there anything that will do something similar (remove markup, leave text *reliably*) and NOT require a Cray to run?

Comment: Hmm.. a Cray would probably be slower :P

Comment: Had any luck yet with the HTML stripping?

Answer (score 13):

lxml.html is FAR more efficient.

http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html

[image]

http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/03/30/python-html-parser-performance/

Looks like this will do what you want.

```
import lxml.html
t = lxml.html.fromstring("...")
t.text_content()
```

A couple of other similar questions: [python [lxml] - cleaning out html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950131/python-lxml-cleaning-out-html-tags)

[lxml.etree, element.text doesn't return the entire text from an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770191/lxml-etree-element-text-doesnt-return-the-entire-text-from-an-element)

[Filter out HTML tags and resolve entities in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486/filter-out-html-tags-and-resolve-entities-in-python)

### UPDATE:

You probably want to clean the HTML to remove all scripts and CSS, and then extract the text using `.text_content()`

```
from lxml import html
from lxml.html.clean import clean_html

tree = html.parse('http://www.example.com')
tree = clean_html(tree)

text = tree.getroot().text_content()
```

(From: [Remove all html in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973325/remove-all-html-in-python))

Comment: Hi, I'm actually looking into that right now. lxml.html doesn't seem to have a straightforward "remove all markup and leave text content" option; I'm downloading lxml as we speak, maybe .parse() is what I'm looking for? Anyway, thanks a bunch. If a simple help(lxml.html.parse) will solve it then, woo.   -- even if not, thanks a ton for the input.

Comment: @WaxProlix, a simple `.text_content()` should be all that you need, with a cleaning first for good measure :)

Comment: +1 for adding the `clean_html` step.  If you skip it, then your output will look pretty bad. For example: `lxml.html.fromstring("foo <script>bar</script>").text_content()` will yield `foo bar`, when you probably expect `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

use cleaner from lxml.html:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner
>>> cleaner = Cleaner(style=True) # to delete scripts styles objects comments etc;)
>>> html = lxml.html.fromstring(content).xpath('//body')[0]
>>> print cleaner.clean_html(html)
```