# Python lxml: insert text at given position relatively to subelements

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'd like to build the following XML element (in order to customize figure number formatting):

```
<figcaption>
<span class="fignum">Figura 1.2</span> - Description of figure.
</figcaption>
```

but I don't know how to specify position of text. In fact, if I create the subelement before creating text,

```
import lxml.etree as et
fc = et.Element("figcaption")
fn = et.SubElement(fc, "span", {'class':'fignum'})
fn.text = "Figure 1.2"
fc.text = " - Description of figure."
```

I get an undesired result (text is positioned before subelement):

```
<figcaption>
 - Description of figure.<span class="fignum">Figure 1.2</span>
</figcaption>
```

How can I specify position of text relatively to subelements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `tail` property of the `span` element:

```
from lxml import etree as et
fc = et.Element("figcaption")
fn = et.SubElement(fc, "span", {'class':'fignum'})
fn.text = "Figure 1.2"
fn.tail = " - Description of figure."

print(et.tostring(fc))
```

> ```
> b'<figcaption><span class="fignum">Figure 1.2</span> - Description of figure.</figcaption>'
> ```

with ElementTree, elements have a `text` inside the element, and a `tail` after and outside the element.

With multiple children, the `text` of the parent is the text before the first child, all the other text inside the element will be assigned to the childrens' `tail`.

Some examples from another answer to this question which has since been deleted:

```
<elem>.text of elem</elem>.tail of elem
<elem>.text of elem<child1/><child2/></elem>.tail of elem
<elem>.text of elem<child1/>.tail of child1<child2/>.tail of child2</elem>.tail of elem
<elem>.text of elem<child1>.text of child1</child1>.tail of child1<child2/>.tail of child2</elem>.tail of elem
```

Comment: So the `tail` property of every subelement show up in XML as text after the subelement. Good to know, thanks.