# Unable to create an appropriate selector to parse a certain string

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors

I've created a selector to scrape a certain string from some html elements. There are two strings within the elements. With my selector within the below script I can parse both of them whereas I expect to get the latter one which is in this case `I wanna be scraped alone`. How can i use any selector which will create a barrier for the first string to be parsed?

Here is the html elements:

```
html_elem="""
<a class="expected-content" href="/4570/I-wanna-be-scraped-alone">
    <span class="undesirable-content">I shouldn't be parsed</span>
    I wanna be scraped alone
</a>
"""
```

I tried with:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

root = fromstring(html_elem)
for item in root.cssselect(".expected-content"):
    print(item.text_content())
```

Output I'm getting:

```
 I shouldn't be parsed
 I wanna be scraped alone
```

Expected output:

```
I wanna be scraped alone
```

Btw, I tried with `root.cssselect(".expected-content:not(.undesirable-content)")` this as well but it is definitely not the right approach. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific example of this question, the best answer is:

```
for item in root.cssselect(".expected-content"):
    print(item.tail)
```

as `element.tail` returns text after the last child. This however will not work if the desired text is before or between child nodes. So a more robust solution is this:

`item.text_content()` according to documentation:

> Returns the text content of the element, including the text content of
>   its **children**, with no markup.

So, if you don't want the text of children, remove those first:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

html_elem="""
<a class="expected-content" href="/4570/I-wanna-be-scraped-alone">
    <span class="undesirable-content">I shouldn't be parsed</span>
    I wanna be scraped alone
</a>
"""

root = fromstring(html_elem)
for item in root.cssselect(".expected-content"):
    for child in item:
        child.drop_tree()
    print(item.text_content())
```

Note that there is some white-space returned as well with this example, which I'm sure is easy to clean.

Comment: Could you tell me why didn't `.text` bring any result? Btw, +1 for your alternative approach.

Comment: It's a bit counter-intuitive, but explained in the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520331/python-lxml-insert-text-at-given-position-relatively-to-subelements

"with ElementTree, elements have a text inside the element, and a tail after and outside the element.

With multiple children, the text of the parent is the text before the first child, all the other text inside the element will be assigned to the childrens' tail."

Which means there is actually a better solution than mine, will update it.

Comment: You left me no choice without accepting your answer. Thanks for the clarity.